# How to handle Imagine exception in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, php-imagine

I suppose I don't manage correctly the exception using Imagine libray.

My code is:

```
use ....
use Imagine\Exception;
....

try {

    $imagine = new Imagine();

    $image = $imagine->open($img_path . DS . "tmpfile." . $extension)
        ->resize(new Box($cwidth, $cheight))
        ->crop(new Point($offsetx, $offsety), new Box(500, 500));

    ...

} catch (Imagine\Exception\Exception $e) {

    die("catch Imagine\Exception\Exception");
    $file = new File($img_path . DS . "tmpfile." . $extension);
    if ($file->exists()) {
        $file->delete();
    }

}
```

but on Imagine Exception, I don't catch it and my script stops.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a qualified name, causing it to resolve with respect to the current namespace, ie `Imagine\Exception\Exception` will resolve to `\CurrentNamespace\Imagine\Exception\Exception`, and since that doesn't exist, you're not catching anything.

Either use the imported namespace, which is `Exception`, ie `Exception\Exception`, which will resolve to `\Imagine\Exception\Exception`, or use a proper fully qualified name, that is, a name starting with a `\`, ie `\Imagine\Exception\Exception`.

See also **[PHP Manual > Language Reference > Namespaces > Using namespaces: Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)**